# Creating and Linking Entries from two Collections in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections: recipes and ingredients. I want to be able to save the ingredient id in the recipe entries.

When a user creates a recipe, they offer an array of ingredients:

```
    "ingredients": [
    {
        "ingredient": "full cream milk",
        "quantity": "4 cups (1L)"
    },
    {
        "ingredient": "elbow macaroni",
        "quantity": "2 cups"

    },
    {
        "ingredient": "cheddar cheese",
        "qualifier": "grated",
        "quantity": "2 cups"

    }
]
```

then, before the recipe is saved, we go through each object in this array and create the ingredient with the given name in Ingredients if it doesn't exist:

```
if(req.body.ingredients != undefined){
    var ingredientsArr = req.body.ingredients;
    for(i=0;i<ingredientsArr.length;i++){
        Ingredient.update({"name":new RegExp(ingredientsArr[i].ingredient,"i")},{$setOnInsert:{"name":ingredientsArr[i].ingredient}},{upsert:true},function(err,ingredients){
            if(err){ return next(err) }
        })
    }
}
```

Now what I need to do is go through `ingredientsArr` and replace every `ingredient:` field with the corresponding `_id`.

I can find the `_id` using `findOne()`:

```
Ingredient.findOne({"name":new RegExp(ingredientsArr[i].ingredient,"i")},function(err, ingredient){
            var id = ingredient._id
})
```

However, I am having scope problems where I can't access `id` outside of the `findOne()` callback function, and I can't access `ingredientsArr` from inside. I'm sure I am missing something obvious here but I couldn't find any help when I tried to google my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (req.body.ingredients != undefined) {
  var ingredientsArr = req.body.ingredients;
  ingredientsArr.forEach((item,i) => {
    Ingredient.findOne({
      "name": item.ingredient
    }, function(err, ingredient) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err)
      }else{
        //do you mean this?
        item.ingredient = ingredient._id
        // or ingredientsArr[i].ingredient = ingredient._id ?
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: D'oh! Right, because for loops aren't asynchronous like forEach() is, right? Works like a charm.

Comment: if you want to use this data, you have to wait all callbacks done, you can flag and check in each callback, but I suggest use promise, refer https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all